# Calculating the angle of a vector

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image][image]

Hi

I'm leaving for my exam in around 20 minutes and I know I've posted a similar one to this before but I didn't find useful hep, well one that I could understand.

im able to get to the far right section so 289 ect, however I can't surpass that point so if someone could please explain to me whilst be as BASIC as possible since whenever someone has tried to help I haven't really understood. Hopefully it's something I can just type in on my calculator

Comment: The last expression can be simplified to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

Comment: Please show me how.... I'm so bad at maths and this would be extra marks... Please be as detailed and as basic as possible, id be so appreciative, you don't understand..

Answer (score 2):

Since $\sqrt{578}=\sqrt{289\cdot 2},$
$$\frac{289}{\sqrt{289}\cdot\sqrt{289\cdot 2}}=\frac{289}{\sqrt{289}\cdot \sqrt{289}\cdot \sqrt 2}=\frac{289}{289\cdot \sqrt 2}=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{1\cdot \sqrt 2}{\sqrt 2\cdot\sqrt 2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}.$$

Here, I used
$$\sqrt{289\cdot 2}=\sqrt{289}\times\sqrt 2,$$
$$\sqrt{289}\cdot\sqrt{289}=289,$$
$$\sqrt 2\times \sqrt 2=2.$$

Comment: @user120993: I think I answered this question once. Does this help?

Comment: how do you go from having two square roots to 2 * squreroot 2?

Comment: @user120993: I don't understand what you mean. What are you talking about? There is no $2\sqrt 2$.

Comment: you go from have squareroot 289 * squareroot 289 * square root 2, to then just 289 * squareroot 2

Comment: oh okok I see one moment

Comment: How did you go from 1/root2  to  = 1 * root 2/ root 2 * root 2 = root 2/2

Comment: I multiplied both the numerator and the denominator by $\sqrt 2.$ (This means I multiplied both by $1$, so they are equal), then calculated each of the numerator and the denominator.

Comment: Is my calculator on the wrong settings, I keep getting decimals rather than fractions?

Comment: Well, no need to use calculator in this question. You'll get $\sqrt 2/2$. Then, you can find the answer in your table. so please don't use the calculator.

Comment: @user120993: Is there anything unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Simplify root(289) into 17 and root(578) into 17root(2), simplify to 1 over root(2), by dividing top and bottom by 289 (17 squared), you're left with 1 over root(2), which is equivalent to root(2) over 2. Look at the cosine table so the angle is 45.

Comment: how do I do root(578) into 17 root (2) ?

Comment: simplifying surds. root(578)=root(278)xroot(2).

Comment: root (278) = 17

Comment: ok so I do root 278x2 which gives me 33.346664, now ?

Comment: work in exact values, you don't need a calculator, just leave it as root(278)xroot(2). The answer of root(278) is 17, so the surd simplifies to 17xroot(2)

Comment: I don't really understand, I don't know the meaning of "surd"? also I have 8 minutes before I leave :D

Comment: a surd is just a root of a number...left as a root

Comment: I don't really understand this, I doubt i'll be able to get it now. THanks for trying anyway